# PHP How to create dynamic array with a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I feel like I am missing something very basic, or maybe it's a dumb question but here goes:

I need an array of the URL, but it needs to be dynamic based on $numberOfinstances.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<?php
$numberOfinstances = 3;
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $numberOfinstances) {
    $arr = array(
        '../../../toolbox'.$i.'/importer/tokens.CC.csv',    
    );  
    $i++;
}
print_r($arr);
```

I am getting this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ../../../toolbox3/importer/tokens.CC.csv
    )
```

What I need is this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ../../../toolbox1/importer/tokens.CC.csv,
    [1] => ../../../toolbox2/importer/tokens.CC.csv,
    [2] => ../../../toolbox3/importer/tokens.CC.csv
    )
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$arr` on each pass through the loop, instead of adding to it. Change your code to something like this (note the change to `$arr[]` in the loop, to push a new value into the array; and note that we just push a string (rather than an array) into the array):

```
$numberOfinstances = 3;
$i = 1;
$arr = array();
while ($i <= $numberOfinstances) {
    $arr[] = '../../../toolbox'.$i.'/importer/tokens.CC.csv';  
    $i++;
}
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nRUgV)

Comment: Variations on this come up quite often - wonder how easy it would be to come up with some sort of reference answer so future ones could be marked as duplicates?

Comment: @NigelRen there probably is one somewhere but I struggle to find it. I'd be happy to work with you on one and then go through and close them all as dupes...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are overlapping array, Here you can use `array_push()` to over come that issue,

Try this

```
<?php
$numberOfinstances = 3;
$i = 1;
$arr = array();
while ($i <= $numberOfinstances) {
    array_push($arr,'../../../toolbox'.$i.'/importer/tokens.CC.csv');
    //$arr[] = '../../../toolbox'.$i.'/importer/tokens.CC.csv';  
    $i++;
}
print_r($arr);
```